# how to I displace a string with another one in the same row

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Proteins = c("A0A0J9YWL0;Q9Y4K1-2;Q9Y4K1", "H0YLZ8;P15144", 
"P08238", "P63261;P60709", "P10809", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", "A0A087WYX8;Q14CM0", "B4DNK4;P14618-3;P14618;P14618-2;H3BR70", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "P07737;K7EJ44"
), `data type BO_10min` = c(NA, "By whama", NA, "By whama", "By TM/T", 
"By TM/T", "By TM/T", NA, NA, "By TM/T", "By TM/T", NA), `data type BO1_1min` = c(NA, 
NA, "By TM/T", "By TM/T", "By TM/T", "By TM/T", "By TM/T", NA, 
"By TM/T", "By whama", "By TM/T", "By TM/T"), `data type BO1_20min` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "By whama", NA, "By TM/T", "By whama", NA, NA, "By TM/T", 
"By TM/T", NA)), .Names = c("Proteins", "data type BO_10min", 
"data type BO1_1min", "data type BO1_20min"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I am trying to paste the protein in each row where there is a letter or number for example

The first row all are empty so nothing will be paste 
the second row column of `data type BO_10min` has a `By whama`so it will change to `H0YLZ8;P15144`

The output will look like the following

```
df<- structure(list(Proteins = c("A0A0J9YWL0;Q9Y4K1-2;Q9Y4K1", "H0YLZ8;P15144", 
"P08238", "P63261;P60709", "P10809", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", "A0A087WYX8;Q14CM0", "B4DNK4;P14618-3;P14618;P14618-2;H3BR70", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "P07737;K7EJ44"
), `data type BO_10min` = c(NA, "H0YLZ8;P15144", NA, "P63261;P60709", 
"P10809", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", 
NA, NA, "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", NA), 
    `data type BO1_1min` = c(NA, NA, "P08238", "P63261;P60709", 
    "P10809", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", 
    NA, "B4DNK4;P14618-3;P14618;P14618-2;H3BR70", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
    "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "P07737;K7EJ44"), `data type BO1_20min` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, "P63261;P60709", NA, "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", 
    NA, NA, "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
    NA)), .Names = c("Proteins", "data type BO_10min", "data type BO1_1min", 
"data type BO1_20min"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

From the above, I only want those rows that have specific proteins for example `A0A0G2JS76` and or `P07737`

So the last df will be this

```
df<- structure(list(`A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7` = c("A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "P07737;K7EJ44"
), `A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__1` = c("A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", NA), `A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__2` = c("A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", "P07737;K7EJ44"
), `A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__3` = c("A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", NA)), .Names = c("A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7", 
"A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__1", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__2", "A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7__3"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this post asks two questions.

1. How to replace the non-NA values in all the other column based on one column? In this case, use the element in `Protein` to replace all other non-NA values.
2. How to filter the data frame by particular strings?

Here is a solution for the first part. The starting point is the first `df` you provided. The idea is to use `lapply` to apply a user-defined function replacing every non-NA values by the same position in the `Proteins` column. `2:ncol(df2)` is a way to skip the first column.

```
df2 <- df
df2[, 2:ncol(df2)] <- lapply(df2[, 2:ncol(df2)], 
                             function(x){
                               x[!is.na(x)] <- df2$Proteins[!is.na(x)]
                               return(x)
                             })
```

After running the above code, `df2` now becomes the same as the second `df` you provided in your post.

Here is a solution for the second part. The idea is to use `grepl` to check if there are matching strings in the `Proteins` column.

```
df3 <- df2[grepl("A0A0G2JS76|P07737", df2$Proteins), ]
df3
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#                 Proteins   `data type BO_10min`   `data type BO1_1min`  `data type BO1_20min`
#                    <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>
# 1  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
# 2 A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;
# 3  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
# 4  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
# 5          P07737;K7EJ44                   <NA>          P07737;K7EJ44                   <NA>
```

My `df3` is different than your third `df`, but I assume my `df3` makes more sense as your third `df` has a strange column name, which looks like the first row of the filtering results.

Comment: thanks , it is definitely a constructive and amazing solution. I am happy that I am learning from yours code.Thanks. I liked it and accepted it

Answer (score 1):

```
 dat=na.omit(data.frame(t(apply(df,1,function(x) {x[!is.na(x)]=x[1];x}))))
 dat
                  Proteins     data.type.BO_10min     data.type.BO1_1min    data.type.BO1_20min
 4           P63261;P60709          P63261;P60709          P63261;P60709          P63261;P60709
 6   A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
 7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;
 10  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
 11  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7
```

Check whether that's what you need.

If you wanted to add a counter,

```
 data.frame(dat[1],t(apply(dat[-1],1,paste,1:3,sep="_")))
                  Proteins                       X1                       X2                       X3
 4           P63261;P60709          P63261;P60709_1          P63261;P60709_2          P63261;P60709_3
 6   A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_1  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_2  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_3
 7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7; A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;_1 A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;_2 A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7;_3
 10  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_1  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_2  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_3
 11  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_1  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_2  A0A0G2JS76;A0A0G2JMX7_3
```

Comment: I gave the output I look for. are they similar? not really but thanks for your thought